# User in India trying to reach external address hosted in US-EAST traceroutes into infinity once it hits the GCE network

Tags: google-compute-engine, traceroute

External user is attempting to access an https page, the page is accessible from his cellphone but not his work network. The traceroute shows his connection making it out of his network and hanging at a google owned IP address.

Is there something I need to configure in GCE to allow for him to access this server because he is in a different region of the global?

My take on the Region GCE documentation is that once the External facing IP address is made available it is accessible globally. Regions have more to do with datacenter location of physical resources being assigned for latency and ha.

This trace route makes it to the destination..

```
dev$ traceroute -I <Redacted>
traceroute to <Redacted> (<Redacted>), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1 <Redacted> 10.195 ms  19.027 ms  9.007 ms
 2 <Redacted>  12.740 ms  10.909 ms  12.472 ms
 3 <Redacted>  16.961 ms  10.587 ms  11.909 ms
 4 <Redacted>  17.748 ms  14.106 ms  12.936 ms
 5  hu-0-11-0-7-pe01.nota.fl.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.82.18)  19.486 ms  11.262 ms  11.885 ms
 6  as15169-2-c.nota.fl.ibone.comcast.net (66.208.228.98)  75.678 ms  58.856 ms  63.486 ms
 7  209.85.253.120 (209.85.253.120)  15.945 ms  12.035 ms  20.278 ms
 8  72.14.239.172 (72.14.239.172)  43.354 ms  43.875 ms  38.440 ms
 9  216.239.50.211 (216.239.50.211)  37.975 ms  48.105 ms  44.817 ms
10  * * *
11  76.207.196.104.acc.googleusercontent.com (<Redacted>)  76.549 ms  39.016 ms  43.469 ms
```

This one does not..

```
MacBook-Pro:COMPANY <Redacted>$ traceroute -I <Redacted>(<Redacted>), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets

 1  <Redacted>Internal IP address  (<Redacted>)  3.590 ms  2.191 ms  2.257 ms

 2  abts-mum-static-<Redacted>.airtelbroadband.in (<Redacted>)  26.894 ms  25.567 ms  26.232 ms

 3  * * *

 4  125.18.13.137 (125.18.13.137)  26.140 ms  25.538 ms  25.579 ms

 5  182.79.235.249 (182.79.235.249)  26.181 ms  26.694 ms  25.816 ms

 6  72.14.220.197 (72.14.220.197)  26.550 ms  26.441 ms  32.273 ms

 7  209.85.254.138 (209.85.254.138)  26.076 ms  27.469 ms  26.499 ms

 8  216.239.50.171 (216.239.50.171)  48.807 ms  46.912 ms  58.771 ms

 9  216.239.63.211 (216.239.63.211)  80.039 ms  91.795 ms  79.793 ms

10  66.249.95.132 (66.249.95.132)  149.171 ms  148.670 ms  162.317 ms

11  209.85.142.51 (209.85.142.51)  302.954 ms  239.236 ms  286.945 ms

12  209.85.248.221 (209.85.248.221)  276.747 ms  250.484 ms  289.642 ms

13  72.14.239.208 (72.14.239.208)  306.111 ms  320.594 ms  306.596 ms

14  209.85.143.167 (209.85.143.167)  410.281 ms  326.247 ms  411.478 ms

15  72.14.234.174 (72.14.234.174)  326.224 ms  359.135 ms  408.716 ms

16  216.239.50.211 (216.239.50.211)  409.802 ms  320.752 ms  312.316 ms

17  * * *

18  * * *

19  * * *
Continues for 30+ lines
```